# Publish Report From SAP BO to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, reports, business-intelligence

How can scheduled reports from SAP BO on-premises be published to a document library in SharePoint Online?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answering to the question primarily requires knowledge of SAP products.

Comment: @moe Heavy handed forums administrator in my opinion. It's a question about publishing to a SharePoint Online Document library primarily. It's possible in previous on-prem versions of SharePoint. Many organisations use both platforms & require answers to these questions because both products are often used together & now there's a new scenario with SharePoint Online.

Comment: Publishing to a SP document library isn't essentially anything else than just *moving* a document to its destination. This can be done e.g. with a PowerShell controlled by a system's task, which moves documents to location A. If you need to control the metadata and e.g. the destination possibilities, you can use e.g. Drop Off Library. I would give this as an answer, but I have no clue what sort of documents SAP pushes out. They might be in a format i-dont-know-X which again would change the plan.